# Find the complete integral of $(p+q)(px+qy)=1$.

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Find the complete integral of $(p+q)(px+qy)=1$,where  $p={ \partial  z \over \partial x},q={ \partial  z \over \partial y}$.

*My Attempt*:

The given equation is : $f(x,y,z,p,q)=(p+q)(px +qy)-1$. So,[Charpit's auxiliary equations](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/partial_diffeqs/charpits_method_compl_int.pdf) are given by: $${dp \over p(p+q)}={dq \over q(p+q)}= {dz \over 0}={dx \over {-q(x-y)}}={dy \over {-p(y-x)}}$$. Now, from $${dp \over p(p+q)}={dq \over q(p+q)} \implies {dp \over p}={dq \over q} \implies p=aq,\,a $$ being arbitray constant. Now, I have to use $$dz=pdx+qdy=q(adx+dy)$$ . Now,I am stuck. The answer is given of the form: $$z(a+1)^{\frac 12}=2(ax+b)^{\frac 12}+b$$

I have used the formula ${dz \over {-pf_p-qf_q}}={dp \over {f_x+pf_z}}={dq \over {f_y+qf_z}}={dx \over {-f_p}}={dy \over {-f_q}}$. Here, $f_x={\partial f \over \partial x}$,.....

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. $p={ \partial  z \over \partial x},q={ \partial  z \over \partial y}$

Comment: I have used the formula ${dz \over {-pf_p-qf_q}}={dp \over {f_x+pf_z}}={dq \over {f_y+qf_z}}={dx \over {-f_p}}={dy \over {-f_q}}$. Here, $f_x={\partial f \over \partial x}$

Comment: i used the same formula for dz on mathematica, Simplify[- p D[(p + q) (p x + q y) - 1, {p, 1}] - 
  q D[(p + q) (p x + q y) - 1, {q, 1}]]

Comment: btw did you check that it satisfies the given PDE?

Comment: check your charpit's equation

Answer (score 1):

The given equation is: $f(x,y,z,p,q)=(p+q)(px +qy)-1 = p^2x+pqy +pqx+q^2y-1 =0$

Thus the Charpit's auxiliary equations are:
$${dp \over p(p+q)}={dq \over q(p+q)}= {dz \over ...}={dx \over {-(2px+qy+qx)}}={dy \over {-(py+px+2qy)}}$$
Taking the first two equations we get, $p =aq$ for some constant $a$. Putting it in original equation we get $$q^2 = {1 \over (a+1)(ax+y)}$$ and $$p^2 ={a^2 \over (a+1)(ax+y)}$$
Thus $p = {a \over \sqrt{(a+1)(ax+y)}}$ and $q= {1 \over \sqrt{(a+1)(ax+y)}}$. Putting this values of $p,q$ in $dz = pdx +qdy$ we get, $$dz = {d(ax+y)\over \sqrt{(a+1)(ax+y)}}$$

Then integrating we get, $$z(a+1)^{\frac 12}=2(ax+b)^{\frac 12}+b$$ where $a,b$ are constants.